# Send_keys method in selenium doesn't works in Chrome

Tags: python, selenium, selenium-webdriver, selenium-chromedriver

I'm writing autotests in Python for web site UI and after the last driver update for Chrome, the send_keys() method started working strangely.

I need to send a string to an input field, for example:

```
name = self.driver.find_element(my_css_selector)
name.clear()
name.send_keys('my name')
```

If this field is empty, the text appears in it - '**My name**'.
If you write something in this field, for example a word - '**Name**', then it says '**NameMy name**'.

Added time.sleep after each step, the bug occurs at the moment of send_keys. After clear - the field becomes clear, but then the old value appears from somewhere.

In Firefox browser - everything works fine, but in Chrome - problems. Has anyone encountered the same problem? I want to run tests in Chrome + it works faster, I would be grateful for any help

Comment: Please provide the DOM on which you faced the issue and also if there is any error encountered in the script. This post has nothing which we can do to actually reproduce the issue.

Comment: @KumarRishabh I don't have any errors, just what I erased is added to my string to the beginning. 
The DOM is not important here, because the problem occurs with any input field on any site, unless that field is empty. 
+ the problem occurs only in Chrome browser after the last update. 
In Firefox browser similar actions work as it should.

Comment: It's got to be something to do with the site you are working with. It's storing previous values or something. If you clear, sendkeys A, clear, sendkeys B... are you saying that the text in the field is AB?

Comment: @JeffC yes, you are right. It's will be - AB

Answer (score 1):

Your problem is not reproducible.

```
import time
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.chrome.service import Service
from webdriver_manager.chrome import ChromeDriverManager
from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By


url = r"https://stackoverflow.com/questions/74113909/send-keys-method-in-selenium-doesnt-works-in-chrome"

driver = webdriver.Chrome(service=Service(ChromeDriverManager().install()))
driver.get(url)

elem = driver.find_element(By.NAME, "q")
elem.clear()
elem.send_keys("my name")
time.sleep(5)
elem.clear()
elem.send_keys("you name")
time.sleep(5)
driver.close()
```